# How can I determine if I need to create a wallet?

Tags: eos

I'm writing an automation script that creates a wallet when necessary.  the problem I have is that `cleos wallet list` gives me an empty result:

> Wallets:
>   []

**even when there is a wallet already in existence**, because I need to open it first with `cleos wallet open`

this means that I cannot rely on the list command to tell whether I need to create a wallet.  but of course, if I try to open a wallet when none has been created, it fails

so what is the recommended way to determine whether my wallet already exists?

**Addendum I**

I have a similar issue with `cleos get accounts`.  see: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/7395

Answer (score 0):

```
./cleos wallet unlock
./cleos wallet list
```

The command show the wallet lists. And then the result is

```
[
  default *
]
```

In the beginning you create the wallet. you can't see anything. But a wallet exists.

So you can import your private key and the key is used by signature